# reading NFC tag through tablet

Tags: nfc, android

I want assistance for writing an application for Android Tablet to pass NFC tags over it where it link automatically to social sites.

Comment: Your question is way too generic, try coding something first then asking once you have a more specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, there are no tablets that support NFC.

Answer (score 0):

There are USB NFC readers (ACR122U) that in theory could be controlled by an Android 3.1 tablet which supports USB host mode. You'd have to experiment though to be able to talk to the reader, no official support for it atm